# Getting only one part of an HTTP GET Request

Tags: javascript, http, get

I want to use the Rest API of Github, but I only need a small part of the info returned in JSON from the GET request. Is it possible to get exactly what I need in order to avoid the extra network usage? This will be done in javascript, but I guess if it's possible it would work on different frameworks.

Comment: "What you get" is determined by the server. If you don't have control over the server or the server has no method for "getting a small part of the info", then no, there is no way.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I hoped it would be possible to send a parameter like a JSON key and have the API handle it without extra methods.

Comment: that might be possible, but you've said nothing about the server or the REST API. The only way to determine that would be to carefully read the documentation for the API.